# How do I add scripts from one document to another?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a script from one of my google documents, which in that document I was able to access via Tools->Script Manager. How can I access its function from another document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you can not. But there is an enhancement request that ask for a similar functionality...you could star it to keep informed on its evolution and mark your interest.See [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2873)

Comment: Libraries have full access, correct, wouldn't using a library be a way to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment :-) libraries have I need access but they need a minimal script to call library functions so this is not exactly what you asked for... I guess one day it will be possible to have access you our scripts from any of our files..., till then we have to copy code or work from templates...

Comment: Should read: ......libraries have indeed... android auto complete is funny sometimes :-)